# How to make the following code coverage up to 100%

Tags: c#, unit-testing

```
public void test(int a)

{
    if (a<=3)
      {...}
    else if (3<a && a<=8)
      {...}
    else
      {...}
}
```

The above code is typed in vs 2010 and create UT for it.
I tried to set the parameter a to be 2,3,4,8,9. seems it already covers all the code. but after running the UT, the code coverage still not be up to 100%.
Any suggestion will be very appreciate!

Comment: Can you show us the bodies of the if / else blocks?

Comment: Does your code coverage tool indicate what part of your code isn't covered?

Comment: @user, don't restate the `else`, we see that. The question regards the possibility of additional conditional logic inside the blocks *we can't see*.

Comment: Perhaps the code coverage tool wants 7 to be included, or some number that may have meaning in one of the (not shown) if/else blocks above.

Comment: We can only speculate as long as we don't see if there's any more conditional logic inside the blocks.

Comment: no any special logic in the block, you can just type console.writeline("test").

Comment: Interest question, coverage = 0)

Comment: @Kak, for that kind of things you should write an answer, not edit the question (as if it was information provided by the asker).

Comment: no it will be marked as edited. I can't write it as answer because it isn't) I will have a lot of minuses). (I also detalize question)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible for the `3<a` test to come out false (because the first test has already disposed of that), so the jump from `3<a` to the bottom `else` block is never executed.

Comment: if a is between 4 and 8, it will jump to else if

Comment: if a is more than 8, it will go to else block

Comment: The jump from `a<=8` to the final else block does get exercised, but the code path that skips the `a<=8` test because `3<a` is false lacks coverage (because it is impossible for it to be taken).

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you cannot cover the block of code with a test is often a good indication that you may simplify your code without losing any of the execution paths. Consider the following code that does the same thing with 100% coverage:

```
    public void test(int a)
    {
        if (a <= 3)
        {
        }
        else if (a <= 8)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
```